# "Kernel Panic not syncing " error

Tags: kernel

When I am trying to open gnome I face this error -

```
kernel panic not syncing:attempted to kill init!exit code=0*00007f00
```

how to solve it?

Comment: Ubuntu version? GNOME version?

Answer (score 0):

checks whether its processor and 32 or 64 -bit and 32 -bit because if you need to install  the 32- bit version , if you are using VirtualBox you need to enable the Hyper -V from your bios event To use 64-bit versions except to the hyper- v you must be enabled ,download a 32 -bit version and enable the configuration of your virtual instance the pae / nx